# Add property manually?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code...

```
function foo(type) {
    if(foo.type == undefined) foo.type = 0;
}
```

What I'd like it to do is create a new property on the `foo` object for each "type" that comes through and set that property to zero (and later begin counting each time a "type" comes through). However, I hit a mental blip, in this case `foo.type` is probably evaluated as the property `type`, on `foo` and not whatever the variable `type` refers to.

I need to convert the value of `type` to a property, any ideas?

And yes I know this question's name sucks, if you think of something better just edit the quesiton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function foo(type) {
    if(foo[type] == undefined) foo[type] = 0;
}
```

You probably want to use `=== undefined` so you won't get any [unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/437049)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! I looked for this on W3C, no mention what-so-ever in the JS object, array or variable lessons.

Comment: `var a = null; console.log(a == undefined);`

Comment: `var a = null, undefined = 'not Im defined'; console.log(a === undefined);` ;-)

Comment: Ok, that's fair but, really? redefining undefined?

Comment: @NicoSantangelo: well, you cannot be sure in anything when you use 3rd party plugins or whatever. It silly indeed, but still possible :-)

Comment: @zerkms: Third party plugins can't redefine `undefined` in any modern browser. The only shared scope is the global, and `undefined` isn't writeable.

Comment: @Crazy Train: if you combine files before minification (as we all do) - it's easy to get http://jsfiddle.net/xULxd/

Comment: @zerkms: Your code example is running in a `window.onload` handler, so it's not global. You're right that if you combined all files, and wrapped the entirety of them in a function, then you could shadow the global `undefined`, but that would be an odd thing to do. http://jsfiddle.net/xULxd/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
if (typeof foo[type] === 'undefined') {
    foo[type] = 0;
}
```